# chmod: invalid mode: `+a'

Tags: 10.04, command-line, permissions, chmod

System: ( lsb_release -a )

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid
```

This is my command:

```
sudo chmod +a "www-data allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

Docs:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

Error:

```
chmod: invalid mode: `+a'
Try `chmod --help' for more information.
```

Why doesn't this work? Isn't the +a standard chmod?

UPDATE:

Looks like this is a OSX only mod:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html

Comment: try +x instead of +a

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"+a" is not a standard argument, no. Follow the next step in the linked documentation.

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

Info on what the "+a" does for chmods that use it:

> +a      The +a mode parses a new ACL entry from the next argument on the commandline and inserts it
>                into the canonical location in the ACL. If the supplied entry refers to an identity already
>                listed, the two entries are combined.

Comment: link is here https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/file_permissions.html

     HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)

 sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
 sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var

Answer (score 2):

That is Mac OS X syntax. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) for proof. 
Ubuntu's chmod doesn't include this option.